# Find the vulnerability in the C program

Tags: c, security, c-strings

Studying for an exam in software security and came across this but can't find the vulnerability. If you input the name "John Doe" and the salary 4000 then the program will write the string "John Doe: $4000". From what I can tell the program accounts for \0, there is no format string bug, no buffer overflow. Don't know what I missed.

Edit: Forgot to add that the "name" parameter can be assumed to a valid null-terminated string.

```
/* Calculates the number of letters (i.e. digits) that are needed to represent a decimal number as an ASCII string */
size_t count_digits(unsigned int number)
{
    unsigned int left = number;
    size_t n= 0;
    while(left != 0) {
        left = left / 10;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

void add_record(const char* name, unsigned int salary)
{
    char buffer[256];

    size_t len = strlen(name);
    size_t num_digits = count_digits(salary);

    /* 5 extra bytes required for colon and space after name + dollar sign, endline and NULL-terminator */
    if(len > SIZE_MAX - 5 || len + 5 > SIZE_MAX - num_digits) {
        printf("integer overflow");
        exit(1);
    }

    len = len + num_digits + 5;

    if (len > sizeof(buffer)) {
        printf("Too long string");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Output formatted string to buffer (in the format string, %s denotes a string, and %u denotes an unsigned int that is printed as a decimal number) */
    sprintf(buffer, "%s: $%u\n", name, salary);

    // Write buffer to file
    fputs(buffer, global_file_handle);
}
```

Comment: Where does `SIZE_MAX` come from, and what is it?

Comment: When and how does this code run? Can the attacker manipulate (change) the value to which `name` is pointing asynchronously?

Comment: @ScottHunter: `SIZE_MAX` is a standard C macro for the maximum value of the `size_t` type, declared in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Giveaways are: `sprintf` is used rather than `snprintf`, the latter is almost always better. And `sprintf` is used to print into a buffer rather than `fprintf` directly to `global_file_handle` rather than to the in this case unneeded intermediate buffer.

Answer (score 5):

`count_digits` incorrectly returns zero for zero. The correct result is one. A name of 251 characters with a salary of zero will require 257 characters (251 for name, 1 for salary, 5 for color, space, dollar sign, new-line, and null), but `len` will be incorrectly computed as 256, and `len > sizeof(buffer)` will not be triggered, so the code will overflow `buffer`.

(Another problem is `strlen` has undefined behavior when `name` is not null-terminated, but the context of `name` is not clear from the problem statement.)

Comment: If `name` is not null terminated, then problem is rather in the calling code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: As stated, the context is not clear. It is possible for this routine to guard somewhat against being passed a string that is not null-terminated, and that could be made a requirement of the routine. To be fair, doing that thoroughly would require access to some mechanism for detecting unmapped memory. But vulnerability analysis goes beyond what the C standard guarantees.

Comment: I'd `#define BUFFER_SIZE (256)`, re-write as `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` and then replace `strlen` with `strnlen(<arg>,BUFFER_SIZE)`... may not be the right way but I find that approach helps avoid magic number problems.

Comment: I would prefer to use `sizeof buffer` for the `strnlen` length argument still.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an example of what the code potentially should have been to avoid the buffer overflow described by Erik Postpischil.

The `count_digits` function is wrong (in case of `0`), but also unnecessary. It is possible to limit the output to `buffer` using `snprintf`:

```
void add_record(const char* name, unsigned int salary)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int len;

    len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s: $%u\n", name, salary);
    if (len >= sizeof(buffer)) {
        printf("Too long string");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs(buffer, global_file_handle);
}
```

Note that if `len` is exactly equal to `sizeof buffer`, this will mean that the resulting string was already truncated. In fact, `len + 1` is the size that `buffer` should have been to prevent truncation.